# ImageDownloader example?

Tags: android

I'm looking at an image cache / downloader for android, I see there's something called ImageDownloader from the sdk examples, also part of this blog post from the team:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

but also see this one which seems to be a more up-to-date version:

http://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/android/imagedownloader/ImageAdapter.java?r=3

I'm not sure which we should be using, I'm guessing the one hosted at the google code project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [this open-source ImageLoader](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/blob/master/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist/ImageLoader.java) from [Fedor Vlasov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95313/fedor). It supports multi-threaded downloading of images with file/memory caching.

```
ImageLoader il = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext()); 
il.DisplayImage(url, (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view));
```

I have been using it for quite a while in a `LazyList` and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the examples above and I had issues in terms of performance, basically the scrolling sometimes was to slow, anyway I think that the version [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/XmlAdapters/src/com/example/android/xmladapters/ImageDownloader.html) on the Android Dev website is the one working better.